# Trying to Define the Value of an Int By Passing It As a Parameter in an Instanced Method (whew)

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, instance

The title sounds really complex. I have been getting better with C# but I definitely need some help here. I'm not even sure if what I want to do is possible in the way I am trying to do it.

I have instanced a method from Class A to Class B, but now I am trying to use that method to define the value of an int that is initialized in Class B.

**CLASS A**

```
class RandomGenerator
{
    public void GetRandomNum(int placeholder)
    {
        Random random1 = new Random();
        placeholder = random1.Next(123456789, 500000000);

    }


}
```

**CLASS B**

```
 public partial class NewEntryPage : Page
{
    public NewEntryPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void finbutton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        int ParseID;
        int ParseAge;
        int AcctNo;
        int CheckNo;

        RandomGenerator instance1 = new RandomGenerator();
        instance1.GetRandomNum(AcctNo);  <--- **//this is what I can't figure out**
```

I'm hoping this question makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: you can pass value types by reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `GetRandomNum` return the value instead of having it passed in.

```
public int GetRandomNum()
{
    Random random1 = new Random();
    int placeholder = random1.Next(123456789, 500000000);
    return placeholder;
}
```

You can then use that value in your function.

```
    RandomGenerator instance1 = new RandomGenerator();
    AcctNo = instance1.GetRandomNum();
```

Comment: Ahhh. So there really wasn't a way to do what I was trying to do. This makes much more sense.

Comment: @helpkelp Actually, there is a way to do it using [`out` parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx), but it would introduce needless complexity to something that is answered much more simply by a return statement. So technically, this doesn't answer the question, but it is absolutely the right answer.

Comment: Thanks Spender. I agree it would make it more complex. I had been studying 'ref' and 'out' and tried to apply it here as well, but had no success. If you have any time, I would love to see how you could apply it here. It's not much but I'll give you an upvote and my appreciation :P!